# Convert NSDateFormatter time of day as hours and minutes as integers

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, integer, int, nsdateformatter

How do i convert an NSDateFormatter to integer?

i have this code to work with:

```
     NSDateFormatter *timeOfDayInt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
     [timeOfDayInt setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
    int currentTime = (int)[timeOfDayInt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];


    if(currentTime >= 1400 && currentTime <= 1500) {
     //do something
}
```

Strangly, this code worked like a day ago, now it returns some weird numbers...
i really cant find a souloution of the problem and i would appriciate an answer..
Thanks!

PS:

If I log the time, `NSLog(@"%@",[timeOfDayInt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);`

it logs correctly.. why dosn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast a `String` to a `int`. I don't know how this should have ever worked.

Try this instead:

```
int currentTime = [[timeOfDayInt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you `convert` `string` into `int` using `intValue`:

```
int currentTime = [[timeOfDayInt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
```

By `casting` `string` to `int`, it cannot be `converted` into `int`.